# What about new versions of third party libraries?

Tags: java, maven

I'm maintaining an open source java library which has itself some dependencies to third party libraries (e.g. commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-1.8.3). During development I just added the most recent version of such libraries to my pom. Now I did some changes to my library and realized that those versions are no more recent.

I'm now wondering which strategy is best practice with such dependencies.

My feeling says run `mvn versions:use-latest-releases test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `mvn versions:display-dependency-updates` and updating relevant libraries by hand.

It is not necessary to always use the latest version of the library.

Usually, should update your dependencies if:

- you need a feature of the new version (for major and minor releases)
- the update resolves a known bug (that affects you)
- the update fixes a security problem.
- resolves an incompatibility with another dependency

Otherwise, consider staying on your current version.

You might, temporarily consider using version ranges `commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:[1.8.0,1.9.0)` to always use the latest bugfix version. Note however, that this results in non-reproducable builds and must be changed before releasing your project.